# Why does one client utilize multiple child processes with KeepAlive On

Tags: apache, apache2

I've noticed that when a client accesses a web page, the requests for that page can potentially utilize several apache child processes, consequently reserving each of those processes for KeepAliveTimeout length (in this case 5).

Is this supposed to happen? Or should a client only be reusing the initial child process, assuming further requests happen before the initial reservation times out (Which they do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While acceding a web page containing external resources (images, CSS, .js), most of the usual browsers use more than one concurrent connections, parallelizing requests in order to get resources faster.
It could be avoided if servers (and browsers) were correctly implementing HTTP pipelining, which unfortunately is pretty rare.